# Automatically publishing migrations not working in ASP.NET-Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I've recently updated my framework from ASP.NET-Core 2.2 to ASP.NET-Core 3.1.  Not sure if that's a factor in this, but latest migration did not automatically apply.  (I think some previous migrations had applied after 3.1 update, so not sure what happened there.) I have to run the migration script in SQL Manager to get them to apply.  I didn't have to do this in the past, so I'm wondering what's happening here.  In program.cs I had context.Database.Migrate();... I've commented this out since it doesn't seem to work and the MS docs recommended against it anyway.  When I check the box in publish for "Apply this Migration on Publish" it does create the script and uploads it to my inetpub folder.  I have to then run that in the SQL manager to apply the migration.  Not a big deal, but wanting to understand what's happening here.  I publish using the File System method since this is an intranet and I can browse to the server on the domain.

Comment: I guess part of my question is how did this work before and what has changed?  I never really understood exactly how it automatically published the migrations before.  (I think I remember the changes being shown in the console when publishing before, but now it just generates the script file?)

Comment: The issue might relate the EF core version. From Asp.net core 3.0, the [Entity Framework Core breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes), the EF Core command-line tool, dotnet ef, is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK. You can check this article: [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: That sounds like it might be it... I have to wait a little while to test this as I don't have a staging server.

Comment: I did change from "self contained" deployment type to "framework dependent".  Did that have anything to do with this?